# What does "broadcast" mean in ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I'm trying to make static network address, and it seems to be that broadcast address and network address need to acquire some ip addresses...I wanna know what these two terms mean..thanks

Answer (score 3):

It means an "address used for transmitting to all the devices in the network".

Consider a 192.168.0.0/24 network.
Its network address is 192.168.0.0 and its broadcast address is 192.168.0.255 (32-network mask = 32-24 == the number of rightmost bits of the IP set to 1).

No device can be assigned either of those two addresses.